# Sample JSON code to get latitude and longitude values from Google API geolocation

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, google, json

I'm a fresher in JSON coding.
I got a sample Google API geolocation console from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/geolocation/ site.

```
{'cellTowers': [
  {
    'cellId': 21532831,
    'locationAreaCode': 2862,
    'mobileCountryCode': 214,
    'mobileNetworkCode': 7
  }
]}
```

But, i'm getting below errors.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "parseError",
    "message": "Parse Error",
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Parse Error"
 }
}
```

Please provide me sample JSON code to get latitude and longitude values from Google API geolocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This google map tutorial may be of some use, it provides info on how to add geojson data as a layer to a google map using the API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/data/importing_data

If you scroll about half way down to the 'Requesting JSONP' section you'll see a sample json file
http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/geojsonp/2.5/week

I hope that helps get you on your way.

Regards,
Rowan

Comment: Dear rowanwins.. thank you for your replay.. it was helpful..